# How can I center align a popup(div) on screen using css, when its content's height/width are not fixed?

Tags: html, css

I was able to center align it properly when the content height and width were known, but if the popup content can vary in height and width, I cant think of any way to do this. Is there any?

Im doing this so that I can have a generic popup component, which will accept content of any height or width, starting from one line to screen max width/height.

Note: No javascript. Im looking for pure CSS methods.

Comment: can you please provide jsfiddle for you scenario.?

Answer (score 2):

The modern and bulletproof way to achieve this in late 2021 is with either [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout) or [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout):

```
<-- HTML -->
<section class="parent flex"><div>Flex</div></section><-- OR -->
<section class="parent grid"><div>Grid</div></section>

<-- CSS -->
<style>
.parent.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.parent.grid {
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;  /* shorthand for justify-content and align-content */
}
.parent {
  width: 100vw; /* whatever */
  height: 50vh; /* whatever */
}
</style>
```

###### Previous answer (Aug 2015):

There are a bunch of ways to do this, the easiest is using transforms:

```
// HTML
<div id="parent"><div id="child"></div></div>

// CSS
#parent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); // needs browser-prefixes 
}
```

Working dynamic example below. Alternative solutions here: http://codepen.io/shshaw/full/gEiDt

```js
function padding(val) {
  document.querySelector("h1").style.padding = val + "em";
}

function text(val) {
  document.querySelector("h1").innerText = val;
}
```

```css
.container {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
}
h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: white;
  padding: 1em;
}
input,
textarea {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>the middle.</h1>
</div>

<textarea type="text" min=1 max=5 step=.1 oninput="text(this.value)">the middle.</textarea>
<input type="range" min=1 max=5 step=.1 value=1 oninput="padding(this.value)">
```

**Note:** The above won't work in IE8.

Answer (score 0):

For vertical alignment have you looked at [this](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/)?

```
 position: relative;
 top: 50%;
 transform: translateY(-50%);
```

For horizontal alignment simply apply `text-align: center` to the containing element.

Answer (score 0):

You can check with the below link.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lacoolj/vTsRk/3/)

```
.reveal-modal {
background:#e1e1e1; 
margin: 0 auto;
width:160px; 
position:relative; 
z-index:41;
top: 25%;
padding:30px; 
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
-moz-box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/834/

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
#popup {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    text-align:center;
}
#popup>div.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    display:block;
    text-align:center
}
#popup .content {
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid blue //For visual feedback.
    max-width:50%; //In case you want to restrict the div width
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="popup">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="content">Hello this is a sample content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Replace the ID with a class in case you want multiple dialogs